# ways to upload PDF in your site

Tags: java, jsp, pdf

I'm using JSP/Java and Spring MVC as framework. I'm going to support uploading PDF files to my site. The site will be uploaded to a free web hosting site.

I want to know which is the best way to support the uploading the PDF files:

1. Save it into database?
2. Save it to the web server ( if this is possible )
3. Save it to your recommendation ( please share what you have in mind )

And also give me a link or tutorial of how may I do this ( if you suggest other than option 1 and 2 ) 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: depends on your resources and your business constraints.  Apert from that it is just someones opinion.

Comment: Can you clarify what is `business constraints` your looking for. I'm just new in developing web application. I'm really a newbie so I really don't have much experience. That is why I'm asking for opinions from experts.

Comment: some people may choose to store their data in the cloud for example, but if your business is concerned about possible leak of information they may not wish to do this.  This is a business constraint.

Comment: Actually the PDF files is just modules/lectures from a subject. So leaking doesn't really matter. What I'm really thinking is the speed of uploading and retrieving, also the convenience of the approach. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Saving file into database is not recommended and i am not sure if anyone would like to do that also.
- Uploading file into web server is also not a good choice because it will increase the load unnecessary.
- The best option is use a dedicated space (it may be cloud or anywhere), and secure it.

You can refer to [spring file upload](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch16s08.html) for reference.

If you are working in localhost for development then i would suggest just use the drive other than where your sever is running. And you can mention the path in web.xml or where ever you want.

Comment: About the cloud. Can you suggest one so I can try that approach?

Comment: Look for **File Hosting**, there are many available. But i am not sure which are the free ones.

Answer (score 0):

Little is achieved by putting "large blobs of binary data" (such as PDFs) into a database.  The only situation where this would be justified is when the data has to be handled transactionally.

If there is nothing to be achieved by putting the PDFs into the database, then don't do it.  You should be able to upload and download large documents faster if they are stored as files in the file system.

How do you do it?  Well there are a variety of ways.  But WebDAV offers a simple "off-the-shelf" solution ... if that is what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

Recommended way is always to use a File System storage service like Amazon S3.

This [application](https://github.com/CloudBees-community/bees-shop-clickstart) on GitHub shows you exactly what you need using AmazonS3 but uploading an image instead of a .pdf. But I am sure that you will find the example really useful.